# Firebase deployment on a subfolder in GitHub Workflows not triggering

Tags: firebase, github, github-actions

I'm trying to setup workflow for my github repo and it seems that it is not triggering.
GitHub repo structure -

[image]

I want to only trigger the workflow on any commit to master if there is a change done in client folder. Below is the yml of the workflow. Please tell me where should I look into to fix this.

```
name: Firebase Deploy

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
    paths: -"client/**"

defaults:
  run:
    working-directory: client

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: "12"
      - run: npm ci
      - run: CI=false npm run build
      - name: GitHub Action for Firebase
        uses: w9jds/firebase-action@v1.5.0
        with:
          args: deploy --only hosting
        env:
          FIREBASE_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_TOKEN }}
```

Note - I've setup the FIREBASE_TOKEN in repo also.

Comment: `paths: -"client/**"` is a syntax error – either you have to use a new line, or `paths: ["client/**"]`

Comment: Well, not a syntax error, but it adds a literal `-` to your path

Comment: It worked. Thanks @BenjaminW.